# Firebase Cloud function mailTransport is not defined

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I am trying to implement a function that will send an email to me if there data is written to my firebase realtime database. However, emails never get sent because of an error stating that "mailTransport is not defined" (see below),

This is the code I have, which I got from another post on stackoverflow.

```
 // Function to send email 
 exports.sendTestEmail = functions.database.ref('/messages')
 .onWrite(event => {
    return sendTestEmail('testemail@gmail.com');
  })

// Sends a notification to me
function sendTestEmail(email) {

   const mailOptions = {
      from: `someone`,
      to: email
   };

   mailOptions.subject = `Welcome!`;
   mailOptions.text = `Hey there! Here is the email notification`;

   return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions).then(() => {
    console.log('New message sent!);
    return
   });
}
```

However, I think this code is correct, the problem is that mailTransport is not recognized. I did install nodemailer through my terminal but this did not make any difference. So, in short, how can I get my code to recognise mailTransport?

Here is the log report of the error:

```
 ReferenceError: mailTransport is not defined 
 at sendTestEmail (/user_code/index.js:32:10)
 at exports.sendTestEmail.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:16:12)
 at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:59:27)
 at next (native)
 at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
 at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
 at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:53:36)
 at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:695:26
 at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: In that code you borrowed, certainly somewhere in that code, the mailTransport variable is defined and assigned?  If not, you'll have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to import `nodemailer` into your script. At the top of `index.js` add

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
```

Note that I got this from the first sample of nodemailer on https://nodemailer.com/about/#example, so I recommend spending some time there if you have a problem.